# Kendo UI AngularJS dropdownlist template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to define a template for my drop-down list items but its just not working. I am not able to access individual items in my dropdownlist. My template should be : "ItemCode: {val}   ItemDesc: {val}", where {val} would be the values Code and Desc respectively for each item in dropdown list.

```
<div class="content-inner kendo-content" data-bind="visible: IsDisplayed">
<div id="mainView" ng-controller="SampleController as ctrl">
    <div>
        <div class="viewDropdownContainer">
            Fund:
            <select kendo-drop-down-list
                    k-data-text-field="'LookupDescription'"
                    k-data-source="ctrl.fundsDataSource"
                    k-ng-model="ctrl.selectedFund"
                    k-template="'<h2>{{ctrl.LookupDescription}}</h2>'"
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you please advise?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be k-data-text-field="ctrl.LookupDescription"

Comment: yes you are right but I was trying some things. But even ctrl.LookupDescription didnt work

Comment: I have made the corrections above.

Comment: Could you post a working sample (plnkr perhaps)?

Comment: I dont know how can I do that. I will try to do that at the earliest though :(. Still pretty new to kendo/angularjs etc

Comment: So I was able to make it work via the statement:

Comment: So I was able to make it work. Now the question I have is how can i do alignment within each item of the dropdown so that my itemDesc in my template (mentioned above) starts from the same margin.